# What´s the difference between positioning a View programmatically with CGRect or with Constraints?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, cgrect

I´m setting up my view programmatically to show up when a button is pressed. My question is what's the difference between positioning a View programmatically with CGRect or with Constraints in storyboard/programmatic constraints?

I tried to set it programmatically and it works fine.

Comment: constraints is less pain in the ass. this is the difference. always stick to autolayout

Comment: I still use autoresizing sometimes but mostly only in very simple situations, like `frame = superview.bounds`.

Comment: Auto layout is substantially richer mechanism. See the official [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) for a nice case-for-action. BTW, if you set `frame`, at the very least you really should set [`autoresizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask), too, in case the superview undergoes any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGRect will not fit all screen sizes as Constraints will. for example. CGRect x: 100, y: 500 may fit a large screen, but for an iPhone SE it will not work because the Item will be off screen. however with constraints like maybe Centre X & Y with a width and height constraint will centre something in the centre of the screen on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified:

- With **CGRect** you give certain *values* and `UIView` will have size and position depending on these values
- With **constraints** you give instructions how these *values* should be created

Comment: `CGRect` probably means autoresizing, which is not really absolute but does not have as much power as autolayout.

Comment: do you mean with "should" that it could fail? Sorry for the stupid question 

Comment: @SwiftNewling if you give breaking constraints, it can fail (not crash of app necessarily)

Comment: @RobertDresler which one do you prefer to use when programming a real app for the App Store

Comment: @SwiftNewling it depends on what you need to achieve